# Protect a 6 inch air hose from physical damage

Tags: dryer, hose, product-recommendation, protection

I've got this 6 inch air duct coming out of my clothes dryer:

[image: 1]

As you can see, we use that space for storing all kinds of junk, and every time I move things around over there, I'm afraid I'll puncture the hose.

Can you think of a good solution for protecting that section of the hose? I was imagining something like a slightly bigger hose-like thing that's goes around the current hose, serving as a protective layer. Is there a product like that, or can you think of a different product that I could improvise with to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: Please tell me it's not routed like that to get to the vent.

Comment: I would look for a different way to route the hose or change to rigid pipe that is smooth inside having the pipe make all the turns + going up and being flex is a lint bunny’s dream. I mention this as you are at a much higher risk of a fire.

Comment: That looks like it is installed to the code "Heath Robinson"....

Comment: What is that plastic flex duct on the left? Is that an outside vent? If it is, I'd switch to using that, rather than the 6" going to somewhere else.

Comment: Please tell me it goes to a vent!

Comment: Can you rotate the dryer 90 degrees and still use it effectively, so the back is to the right in the photo ?

Comment: Are you the owner?  Can you install shelves above the dryer for all your items ?  Or put your items elsewhere in the home, or even on ebay if they're just clutter.

Comment: The only real solution here is to grab a saw, cut a whole in the wall (ie, right next to the exhaust hole of the dryer), and construct a proper vent from there to the outdoors.  All laundry rooms **should have** a **low-level** hole-for-the-dryer-exhaust.

Comment: 6" PVC tube. Either over the hose, or replacing it.

Answer (score 10):

The best thing is to use rigid ducts instead of flexible ducts. A little harder to install as you have to figure out (and possibly do some cutting) exactly what pieces to use for your specific installation, and typically you need to attach several pieces together instead of one long tube. But avoids a lot of the issues of lint collecting inside every "crinkle" in the tube, tube getting easily crushed, etc.

Hopefully with rigid duct you can rearrange things so that you don't have ducts sitting right on top of the dryer (or other appliances).

Comment: If space is an issue, there are low profile duct runs that are really flat.  Not as efficient as a tube, but if you're in a pinch...

Answer (score 4):

The other answers give good advice without actually answering your question. Have you considered cutting two holes in a shoebox and feeding the duct through the holes?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.

Comment: This is totally hilarious  :)  thanks  :)

Comment: A shoe box makes *excellent* kindling to spread the dryer hose fire to the rest of the house.

Comment: This answer could go on [LifeHacks.SE](http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 4):

If you really must have the dryer where it is, and drape the duct like that, then buy some flexible ducting as used for wood burners. It's quite easy to bend around, but the wall is a lot stronger than what you have there. It's designed in part to be an insert in chimneys.

That's the answer to the question, but not the answer to your problem.

That's to re-site the dryer better, and use solid wall tubing - rectangular or round in section, which can, with elbows, make a much neater, safer job. Moving the outlet, through the wall, presumably, may also make it a better job, but may not be possible.

Answer (score 3):

You really need to think about relocating your dryer closer to the vent. Then add some rigid duct. Also, most dryers have more than one exit point for the vent, check them out.

Answer (score 0):

To do what you asked for: attach a shelf to the wall, high enough that the duct fits underneath. Put your loose items on that shelf instead of on the dryer. Optionally, fit a plank underneath the shelf in front of the duct, attach the plank to the shelf and make sure there's a few mm of space between the dryer and the plank (so the vibrations of the dryer don't end up in the plank+shelf).

Replacing the hose with a PVC pipe and/or using a vent closer to the dryer outlet are better solutions.